# type error int object is not iterable on function python

Tags: python, integer, typeerror

```
def screen_size_w(screensize: int, width: int) -> int:
   return ((sum(screensize)) - (sum(width))) / (sum(width))

def screen_size_h(screensize: int, height: int) -> int:
   return ((sum(screensize)) - (sum(height))) / (sum(height))


print(screen_size_h(1600, 500))
print(screen_size_h(2000, 500))
```

when I run it, it gives me the TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, I've seen a lot of people having this problem, and a lot of solutions too, but they didn't really help a lot, I've tried everything I could think of, but I always get the same error. If you could help me in any way, I'd appreciate it

Comment: Be sure to include what line gives you this error. Sometimes the stacktrace can help too!

Comment: Why are you calling `sum` on a single `int` in the first place? While `sum([x]) == x` is true when `x` is an `int`, you cannot simply pass a single `int` to `sum` instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function takes a type `iterable` and returns the sum of all the elements in that iterable. When you pass it a type `int`, as you do here, it throws a `TypeError`, because an `int` is not an `iterable`.

It's probable you want something like this:

```
def screen_size_w(screensize: int, width: int) -> int:
   return (screensize - width) / width
```

`sum()` will give you something like this (from the REPL):

```
>>> ls = [1,2,3]
>>> sum(ls)
6
```

`ls` is a list in this case, an `iterable`. `sum()` moves over this list and adds up all the elements. You can see why it wouldn't make much sense to do this:

```
>>> sum(3)
```

Given the names of your functions, you're clearly trying to determine a ratio between the resolution (?) of a screen and it's width and height. It's probable you can do this math directly, without `sum()`.

Comment: I think we need more information from the OP about why they are using `sum` in the first place. Right now, your answer is little more than a rewording of the original error message.

Comment: @chepner Re-wording with industry terms, though. It *is* important to learn and use those.

Comment: yeah.. I used sum cause screensize and height was ment to be a tuple (as well as width), I shouldn't have printed just a number, sorry, but I shouldn't have asked this, anyways, I think I already know what to do. I feel stupid lol

Comment: @PartyPie Aw! You're not stupid. Learning to notice the stuff you miss the first time around is a big chunk of learning how to program.